# UIView animation for multi views

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am trying to make animation for two views like this:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
CGRect rect = self.oneView.frame;
rect.origin.y =  10;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

    self.oneView.frame = rect;
    self.buttonView.transform = transform;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    ...
}];
```

But only buttonView has rotated. OneView stays in place. But if I comment

```
//self.buttonView.transform = transform;
```

OneView has moved.

Answer (score 0):

`rect.origin.y = 10;` is probably giving you a warning because you can't write directly to a `CGRect`.

You'll have to do `rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, 10.0f, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)`.

Comment: But It is working if I comment this line: self.buttonView.transform = transform;

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between oneView and buttonView? If oneView is a child of buttonView, then this will be an expected effect.

Have you tried to run these animations from 2 separate calls?

Comment: Both added to one parent view as subviews.